# How to list the n'th youngest file (without parsing ls!)

Tags: bash, ls

So I know parsing ls is [bad!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Today I found this nugget:

```
FILENAME=`ls -t $READ_FOLDER | head -1`
```

So I believe originally this was designed to grab the newest filename, I actually now want to adapt it, to grab maybe the **5th** newest file as the process that's checking it is a little slow, and so we can't be sure they have been processed yet.

I'm working in bash, but not opposed to a sh generic solution too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GNU `find` to list the files with the modified time expressed as epoch time, then use `sort` to sort the list, finally `head` and `tail` to get the desired numbered file name :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k1,1nr | head -5 | tail -1
```

Comment: Workaround for unusual filenames: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -z -k1,1nr | awk -v 'RS=\0' 'NR==5'`

Answer (score 8):

Perlishly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %files_by_mtime;

foreach my $file ( glob ( "./*" ) ) {
   my ( $mtime ) = (stat($file))[9];
   $files_by_mtime{$file} = $mtime; 
}

foreach my $f (  sort { $files_by_mtime{$b} <=> $files_by_mtime{$a} } keys %files_by_mtime ) {
   print "$f $files_by_mtime{$f}\n";
}
```

Reducing to:

```
perl -e '%f = map { $_ => (stat)[9] } glob("./*");print "" . ( sort { $f{$b} <=> $f{$a} } keys %f )[4];'
```

Where the "N"th file is 4, because perl arrays start from zero.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have access to GNU tools (you do if you're running Linux), I would use `stat` instead. For example:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Sep 15 16:49 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Sep 15 16:39 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Sep 15 16:29 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Sep 15 16:19 file4
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Sep 15 16:09 file5
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Sep 15 15:59 file6
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Sep 15 15:49 file7
```

So, the 5th newest file is `file5`. To print just that, you can do:

```
$ stat --printf '%Y %n\0' * | sort -zrnk1 | 
    awk -vRS='\0' 'NR==5{sub(/^[^ ]* /,"",$0); print}'
```

You could then easily make this into a shell function that can take N (5 in your example) as an argument. Just add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent:

```
nthfile() {
  stat --printf '%Y %n\0' * | sort -zrnk1 |
     awk -vRS='\0' -vn="$1" 'NR==n{sub(/^[^ ]* /,"",$0); print}'
}
```

Note that this will also show you directories. If you need it to match hidden files as well run (assuming you're using bash) `shopt -s dotglob` before the above command.

#### Explanation

- `stat --printf '%Y %n\0' *` : for each file or directory in the current folder, print the modification date in seconds since the epoch (`%s`) and the file name (`%n`) and end each line with `\0` instead of `\n`. This lets us deal correctly with file names containing newline characters.
- `sort -zrnk1` : sort the output in reverse sort order (`-r`), from the newest to the eldest. The `-z` tells `sort` to expect null-terminated input lines. The `-n` tells it to sort numerically and the `-k1` to only consider the first field when sorting.
- `awk`:

  - `-vRS='\0'` : set the input record (line) separator to `\0`;
  - `vn=$1` : set the variable `n` to whatever was given as input to the function;
  - `NR==n{}` : run this only on line `n` (5 in the first example);
  - `sub(/^[^ ]* /,"",$0); print` : substitute all non-space characters from the beginning of the line (`^[^ ]*`) up to the 1st space and print the result

Comment: Don't you need to tell `sort` to sort numerically (`sort -zrnk1` or something like that)?

Comment: Shell pattern `*` does not match filenames starting with `.`.

Comment: @zwol it shouldn't be necessary, no. The output of `stat` will always be seconds since the epoch so `sort` should always deal with it correctly.

Comment: @Roman true but neither does `ls -t` which is what the OP was using. There was no mention of dotfiles in the question. Still, I edited to add the `dotglob` option for bash users.

Comment: Thanks for `dotglob`. About `sort` without `-n`: I believe, it will correctly sort numbers, only if they all have the same length (same amount of digits).

Comment: @Roman and you're quite right! I hadn't considered that, I knew that `sort` was sorting lexically without the `-n` but figured that wouldn't be a problem here since the result would be the same. I hadn't considered the possibility of different digits (since that is extremely unlikely when dealing with seconds since the epoch) but you're absolutely right. That can happen and it should be taken into account. Answer edited and thanks!

Comment: @zwol I stand corrected, see my comment to Roman above. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
print -r -- *(.Dom[5])
```

give you the 5th file in current directory sorted by `m`odification time. Change `m` to `a` to sort by `a`ccess time. `.` and `D` include only regular and hidden files.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this (assuming no newlines in your file names) would be

```
ls -t ... | head -n5 | tail -n1
```

Comment: @don_crissti: this is not parsing (the output) of ls, it's just using it.

Comment: @don_crissti I overlooked the link given by the OP. The problem is not `ls`, but the processing in the pipe which will break at filenames with embedded newlines etc.

Comment: @ThomasErker this is reading the output of `ls` and modifying its output depending on certain criteria. Otherwise known as _parsing_ it. Like most cases of parsing `ls` output, it will fail on file names with newlines.

Comment: As @terdon has pointed out, part of the reason for avoiding ls is that I can't be sure of the file names. Generally they're consistent, but considering the code I quoted, I don't trust them.

Comment: Filenames may not contain "/" or NUL (0x00). Parsing `ls` always leads to pe